# Python pause while true loop until condition fulfilled

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game in python. The game, so far, consists of a single class (animal) and a few variables and methods. You can press one of three keys to attack. It is in a `while True` loop. when you press the  <kbd>1</kbd>  key, it does one attack, and the same for the  <kbd>2</kbd>  and  <kbd>3</kbd>  keys. When run, however, it keeps running this statement over and over:

```
print("""
Use key 1 to do {} damage, key 2 for {} damage, and key 3 for
                {} damage
            """.format(
                Animal.attack0_damage, Animal.attack1_damage, Animal.attack2_damage
))
```

How can I pause the `while True` loop until the user presses one of the keys? If it is needed, the entirety of my code is here.

```
from msvcrt import getch
class Animal():
    health = 100
    mana = 100
    attack0_damage = 1
    attack1_damage = 5
    attack2_damage = 10
    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.type = species
    def stat_mod(self):
        if self.type == "Hippo":
            Animal.health += 30
            Animal.mana -= 5
            Animal.attack0_damage += 10
            Animal.attack1_damage += 10
            Animal.attack2_damage += 10
        elif self.type == "Armadillo":
            Animal.health += 20
            Animal.mana += 10
            Animal.attack0_damage += 1
        elif self.type == "Crocodile":
            Animal.health += 25
            Animal.mana += 5
            Animal.attack0_damage += 5
            Animal.attack1_damage += 5
            Animal.attack2_damage += 5
    def attack(self, whatToAttack):
        while True:
            print("""
                Use key 1 to do {} damage, key 2 for {} damage, and key 3 for
                {} damage
            """.format(
                Animal.attack0_damage, Animal.attack1_damage, Animal.attack2_damage
            ))
            key = ord(getch())
            print(Animal.health)
            print(Animal.mana)
            print(whatToAttack.health)
            if key == 49:
                whatToAttack.health -= Animal.attack0_damage
                print(Animal.health)
                print(Animal.mana)
                print(whatToAttack.health)
            elif key == 50:
                whatToAttack.health -= Animal.attack1_damage
                mana -= 5
                print(Animal.health)
                print(Animal.mana)
                print(whatToAttack.health)
            elif key == 51:
                whatToAttack.health -= Animal.attack2_damage
                mana -= 10
                print(Animal.health)
                print(Animal.mana)
                print(whatToAttack.health)
            else:
                print("Invalid key! You can only press the keys 1, 2, and 3!")
            if whatToAttack.health <= 0:
                print("You beat {}!".format(whatToAttack.name())
                break
        input("Press enter to exit.")
hippo = Animal("Joe", "Hippo")
hippo.stat_mod()
armadillo = Animal("Jeff", "Armadillo")
armadillo.stat_mod()
hippo.attack(armadillo)
```

Comment: You dont have an input() within your loop to stop it from running. Something like...`action = input("Enter an action (press enter to exit): ")`. You have the input  at the bottom, but it is not nested within your loop, therefore you'll never make it to it. I simple fix would be to tab it into your loop?

Comment: `msvcrt.getch` requires a real console and will return `chr(0xff)` without a key press  if your code is in *.pyw file or you run it in an environment like an IDE that redirects stdin. Try to run your script in cmd.exe, it should work.

Comment: I don't think it's related to your loop issue, but all the places you're using class variables like `Animal.health` should almost certainly be using instance variables instead (`self.health`). Currently all animals share the same health pools!

Comment: @Kris: I would, but that doesn't let me use the 'getch' function, and it could be trolled w/ something like typing multiple chars into the input.

Comment: @robyscheck I did, but it breaks down when I try to press 2 or three. once I press it, the window closes.

Comment: @Blckknght that wasn't the problem, but I see your point there. I will implement that in my program.

Comment: @Ranger Thats another issue. Probably you meant `self.mana -= 5` and `self.mana -= 10`

Comment: You really need to replace all `Animal` to `self` in `attack` and `stat_mod`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Would anyone be able to tell me how? In CMD it works, but there's a glitch in which if you press the keys 2 or 3, it crashes. In IDLE, it doesn't pause, and if I try to "attack", nothing happens. I don't think IDLE even notices the keystrokes.

Comment: Scratch that all. I finally realized what @robyscheck was saying:

`self.mana -= 5` and `self.mana -= 10`

meant I had to change what was in the attack function. Thanks for the help, everyone!