# Run TCL code alongside Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799692/python-pause-while-true-loop-until-condition-fulfilled) question, I asked about a game I was making with Python. I have finished the code, without any graphics, but now I want to add those graphics.

I am planning to do it with a determinate progressbar in Tk, modifying the "value" configuration setting as the health and mana of the animals get depleted. (By the way, if you don't understand what I'm talking about, please read the other question - the code gives you some knowledge about what's going on)

However, my tkinter is quite rusty, and as far as I know, there is no "configure" option in it. However, my TCL is fluent enough to do the job. My question has two possible ways to answer: Knowledge on a widget configuration option in tkinter, or how to run TCL code alongside python, with python actively passing values into the TCL code and the TCL code actively configuring its widgets based on those values. To make that shorter:

Is there a configuration option in tkinter, or if not, is there a way to run TCL code with python?

Comment: All widgets have a `configure` method. It's documented in many places.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it in tkinter? I have no idea how.

Comment: Ahhh I see I hadn't found it when I looked it up before. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A reference can be found here http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Progressbar.html

You probably want .start and .step

Comment: A simple example here would help.

Comment: w = ttk.Progressbar(parent, maximum=100); w.step(1.0)

Comment: Seems that an example is not appreciated.